# How to copy file from network share in VB for an windows ce application

Tags: vb.net, windows-ce, impersonation

I am doing an application using vb.net.

What I need is access my computer (win 8) from a windows ce device and copy one file to the windows ce device. 
I already did that but what I need now is an way to pass the user, password and domain. 
I have researched about and found some solutions using System.Security.WindowsImpersonationContext So I think Something similar to that that will work in a windows ce application.

SOrry If you don't get something I have said but I am new on programming and english is not my home language.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `MapDrive` method of the `Network` class from the SDF.  Since it's pretty straightforward, the source for that method is as follows (I leave it to you to get it to VB):

```
public static void MapDrive(IntPtr hwnd, string netRes, string shareName, string userName, string password)
{
    NETRESOURCE NetRes = new NETRESOURCE();         
    NetRes.dwScope = RESOURCE_GLOBALNET | RESOURCE_REMEMBERED;
    NetRes.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
    NetRes.dwDisplayType = RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SHARE;
    NetRes.dwUsage = RESOURCEUSAGE_CONNECTABLE;
    NetRes.lpRemoteName = Marshal2.StringToHGlobalUni(netRes);
    NetRes.lpLocalName = Marshal2.StringToHGlobalUni(shareName);
    NetRes.lpComment = IntPtr.Zero;
    NetRes.lpProvider = IntPtr.Zero;

    int ret = WNetAddConnection3(hwnd, NetRes, password, userName, 1);

    if (ret != 0)
    {
        throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ret, ((NetworkErrors)ret).ToString());
    }

}

private class NETRESOURCE
{
    public int dwScope;
    public int dwType;
    public int dwDisplayType;
    public int dwUsage;
    public IntPtr lpLocalName;
    public IntPtr lpRemoteName;
    public IntPtr lpComment;
    public IntPtr lpProvider;
}

[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
private static extern int WNetAddConnection3(
    IntPtr hwndOwner, 
    NETRESOURCE lpNetResource, 
    string lpPassword, 
    string lpUserName, 
    int dwFlags);

const int RESOURCE_GLOBALNET  =    0x00000002;
const int RESOURCE_REMEMBERED =    0x00000003;
const int RESOURCETYPE_DISK  =     0x00000001;
const int RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SHARE     =     0x00000003;
const int  RESOURCEUSAGE_CONNECTABLE =  0x00000001;
```